# How do I delete a file locally in subversion?

Tags: svn

I am trying to locally delete a file that is under subversion's version control, yet
without affecting the file's status in the repository.

This is the basic sequence I have done to reach the *current* situation:

```
svn co https://..../Path/to/project --depth empty
```

By force of the `--depth empty` swicht, this creates the empty directory `./Path/to/project` although the directory is not empty in the repository.

I cd into the directory:

```
cd Path/to/project
```

and get some files from the repository

```
svn up file.1
svn up file.2
svn up file.3
```

Later, I decide I don't want to see file.2 any longer locally. How can I achieve this? That is, that the local situation is as though I'd never done a `svn up file.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to reach is supported since Subversion 1.6 (I didn't know that either). You have to use the option `svn update --set-depth exclude many-dirs/unwanted-dir`.

So in your case, the following command should remove the file (only) locally, and will not show it when doing `svn st`:

```
svn update --set-depth exclude file.2
```

See the documentation for sparse checkout in the [SVN red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.sparsedirs)

---

Having checked it again with a simple example, I have noticed that it seems to work for directories, but not for files. I have only checked it with the combination TortoiseSVN 1.6.x and SVN server 1.6.x, so I cannot say if it works with SVN 1.7.

Comment: `svn up --help` on a Version 1.6 installation seems to indicate it's possible, however, it won't work. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You just need to delete `file.2` locally (on filesystem level). If you're on UNIX, run `rm file.2` command at your working copy (path where you have checked out to your files).

Comment: But if I delete the file and then do a `svn st` I still see the file with the `!` status.